# Handle Deadlock gracefully

Tags: deadlock

I have a SQL script that got deadlock victimized sporadically with Meta lock.  I do not want to set Deadlock priority as I don’t want to deadlock other query and block other queries.
Rather I would like to allow open transactions to finish their task, and for a  long running queries wait for 10 minutes and then kill it, and roll it back successfully.
Looking for a sample sql script to achieve this goal.

Comment: It would be nice to show what have you tried so far.

Comment: Also adding details as to what SQL version you are using.